# Adding multiple user inputs into comma separated line in shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssl

I have to get user inputs of multiple domain names until the user is done with inputs. Input can be just one domain name or more than one. and the domain name should be separated by a comma `,`.

How can I pass the domain names to the below command. Kindly please help me.

```
keytool -genkey -keystore tc_keystore.jks -keysize 2048 -keypass password -storepass password -keyalg RSA \
 -dname "CN=domain1.com,OU=Devteam,O=Softech,L=Chicago,ST=IL,C=US" \
 -alias domain1.com -ext san=dns:domain2,domain3,domain4,domain5,domain6,domain7
```

As I am new to shell script, I am reading a single user input and store it in a variable and call the variable. like the below one. But When it comes to multiple user input that should be separated by comma, I am stuck.

```
keytool -genkey -keystore $keystore -keysize 2048 -keypass $password -storepass $password -keyalg RSA \
 -dname "CN=$domain1,OU=Devteam,O=Softech,L=Chicago,ST=IL,C=US" \
 -alias $domain1 -ext san=dns:domain2,domain3,domain4,domain5,domain6,domain7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way of letting users supply data to a script is via its command-line arguments.  In this case, it would, for example, be convenient to call your script with a list of domain names. Since the user needs to provide a password and some other key-related parameter, we could develop a script that takes two options and a list of domains.

```bsh
./script -p 'password' -k 'keystore' domain1 domain2 domain3 ...
```

I don't know the `keytool` utility that you are using, but it seems that a user must supply a list of at least two domains rather than just one. The first domain name is used with the `-dname` and `-alias` options, while the `-ext` option takes the second and any other domain name in its value.

The following code uses the idiomatic way of parsing the command-line options and validates that the `keystore` and `password` variables have values. It then calls the `keytool` utility with the data given by the user.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

unset -v keystore password

while getopts k:p: opt; do
        case $opt in
                k)
                        keystore=$OPTARG
                        ;;
                p)
                        password=$OPTARG
                        ;;
                *)
                        echo 'Error' >&2
                        exit 1
        esac
done

shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

if [ -z "$keystore" ] || [ -z "$password" ]; then
        echo 'Missing keystore (-k) and/or password (-p)' >&2
        exit 1
fi

if [ "$#" -lt 2 ]; then
        echo 'Expecting at least two domain names' >&2
        echo '(a main one, and one for the -ext option)' >&2
        exit 1
fi

domain1=$1
shift

IFS=,

keytool -genkey \
        -keystore "$keystore"   \
        -keysize 2048   \
        -keypass "$password"    \
        -storepass "$password"  \
        -keyalg RSA     \
        -dname "CN=$domain1,OU=Devteam,O=Softech,L=Chicago,ST=IL,C=US"  \
        -alias "$domain1"       \
        -ext "san=dns:$*"
```

After the first `shift` statement, the first domain name will be in `$1` and the others in `$2`, `$3`, and so on.  We assign `$1` to the `domain1` variable and call `shift`.  After the second `shift`,  we may use `"$*"` with `IFS` set to a comma to generate a comma-delimited string of the rest of the domain names.  We use this in the value for the `-ext` option.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working now.